# Arrows for carousel

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, jinja2

I have the carousel with images from django

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      {% for ph in photos %}
        <img id="{{ph.pk}}" src="{{ph.photo.url}}">
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      {% for ph in photos %}
        <a href="#{{ph.pk}}"></a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

how can i add arrows for left and right slides?

i tried bootstrap but it didnt work, so im here... :)